# Why is it bad practice to allow to set a collection?

Tags: java

Let's say we have a class with a simple collection (a list for instance). The class contains a constructor, getters and setters. 
I've been told that it is a bad practice to set the collection directly.

```
class Example{
    private String id;
    private List<String> names;

    public Example(String id, List<String> names){
        this.id = id;
        this.names = names;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public List<String> getNames(){
        return names;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names){
       this.names = names;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point the disadvantages of writing the method `setNames()`?

Comment: The same reason you shouldn't return a collection from a getter without a defensive copy. It breaks encapsulation.

Comment: There is the same problem with the constructor as with the setter: because you don't take a defensive copy, the caller can change the list held by `Example`.

Comment: You have no encapsulation.  Presumably the point of an instance this class is to maintain a relationship between an id and a list of names.  But anyone can change the id without changing the names, and change the names without changing the id.  There are therefore no guarantees at all, and you might as well use public variables rather than setters and getters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic behind set and get operations is to allow validation or replacing of inner representation, if you let an external class set the specific implementation, you lose control over the insertion logic (allows duplicates? is ordered?, is mutable?), and you make you object harder to use, as the users of it have to decide that, when is very probable that they don't care.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the built-in collections are mutable, so storing such a value may allow an external class to modify the internal state of your `Example` in a way you did not plan. Consider the following snippet:

```
List<Stirng> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Stack");
names.add("Overflow");

Example example = new Example();
example.setNames(names); 
// example.getNames() returns ["Stack", "Overflow"]

names.add("Exchange");
// example.getNames now returns ["Stack", "Overflow", "Exchange"]!
```

A safer approach could be to copy the contents of the passed list:

```
public void setNames(List<String> names){
   this.names = new ArrayList<>(names);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the private variable names is owned by your class you can ensure that you have control over its contents within the class.  If you change the reference of that variable to a list that gets passed in then you no longer are certain that your instance won't be changed externally since both your class AND the class that passed the new list instance will both have a reference/access to it.  Same is true with getNames() - any class that calls that method now has full access to change the contents of the list externally from the class.

Answer (score 2):

That would give you two ways of changing the contents (`getNames().add(...)` vs. `setNames(Arrays.asList(...))`).
This is confusing.

You should pick a single option and make the other option impossible.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different answer to those here already is that *setters are a bad practice* (*), whether you're setting a collection property or some other type.

To quote *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 15: "Minimize mutability":

> There are many good reasons for [making classes immutable]: Immutable classes
>   are easier to design, implement, and use than mutable classes. They are less prone
>   to error and are more secure.

There is also a description of immutable classes in [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

---

(*) That's not to say that you should never use them; just that you should design classes to be immutable as a default position, and only make them mutable in the few occasions where it is actually required - and that's less often than you might imagine. To quote the same item in Effective Java:

> Classes should be immutable unless there’s a very good reason to make them
>   mutable

Answer (score -2):

Using get and set methods allows you to perform verification and validation on the input before it can cause problems. It can also be used to transform info going into and out of your system for the convenience of the program and user.

Edit

Just to be clear defensive measures are part of the verification and validation I was talking about.

Comment: get and set methods expose the objects *internal state* in the first place violatint the most important OO principle **information hiding / encapsulation**. This may be OK if this class is for *Data Transfer Objects* having no business logic. In any other case get and set methods should be avoided.

Comment: You can program defensively in the methods to transfer just the value and not a reference to the object. The OU has some good material on that.

Comment: *"You can program defensively"* This is wishful thinking. Getters and setters break *information hiding / encapsulation* support *feature envy* which makes the code harder to understand, harder to reuse and harder to maintain. (again: *information hiding / encapsulation* does not apply to  DTOs  so that  getters and setters are OK with them.)

Comment: Then how do you suggest initialising objects and updating values that they contain? How would you obtain information from an object without them?

Comment: As I already mentioned: DTOs have getter/setter. If you want/need to obtain information from an  business object (containing business logic) you have a design problem.

Comment: There is on logic in the example given, it is a DTO.